# get object from another form

Tags: c#, class, object

Every time i get the same problem.
I want to import my already made object in my Beerform. 
When i try to execute this code i everytime get this error: CS0051  C# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type is less accessible than method

Here is my Form1 with the consumer class within.

```
namespace GoedeKillerApp

public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    private Database dbconnection;
    private Consumer consumer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dbconnection = new Database(); 
    }

    private void signupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        consumer = new Consumer(nameTextbox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ageUpDown.Value));

        if (ageUpDown.Value == 0 || nameTextbox.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Voer de gegevens in!");
            if (ageUpDown.Value < 18)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You aren't allowed to create a account");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dbconnection.DatabaseInsert("INSERT INTO consumer(Consumer , Age) VALUES('" + consumer.Name + "' , '" + consumer.Age + "' )");
            if (true)
            {
                this.Hide(); 
                BeerForm beerform = new BeerForm(consumer);                    
                consumer.SaveName(consumer.Name);
                beerform.Show();
                MessageBox.Show("Sign Up Succesful");
            }
        }

    }

    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbconnection.ReadGegevens();
    }
}
```

This is my second form named BeerForm. The problem is that i cant get the class i made in Form 1

```
namespace GoedeKillerApp

public partial class BeerForm : Form
{
    public BeerForm(Consumer consumer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }



    private void BeerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void addbeerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: We need the Consumer's class declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class BeerForm : Form
{
    internal Consumer consumer ;
    public BeerForm(Consumer theconsumer)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        consumer = theconsumer ;

    }

// then use consumer variable in your BeerForm procedures.
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, I'm guessing its the modifier on the `Consumer` class, so that this fails:

```
BeerForm beerform = new BeerForm(consumer);
```

Try changing

```
internal/private class Consumer
```

To

```
public class Consumer
```